# Plotting the output of Solve against another list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How do I plot:

```
{{M1 -> 3.41167*10^6, M2 -> 3.43861*10^6, M3 -> 3.43861*10^6, 
  M4 -> 3.50753*10^6, M5 -> 3.50753*10^6, M6 -> 3.50753*10^6, 
  M7 -> 6.29868*10^6, M8 -> 6.29868*10^6}}
```

against:

```
{{2.85408*10^6, 2.86829*10^6, 2.86829*10^6, 2.90463*10^6, 
  2.90463*10^6, 2.90463*10^6, 5.64623*10^6, 5.64623*10^6}}
```

Do I need to convert the `M1 -> 3.41167*10^6` to `M1 = 3.411` before plotting? If so, how?

Comment: You can access just the numerical values of that list of rules by using `Part` (`[[1]]` gives the first part, `[[All]]` give all parts, etc.),  `{{M1 -> 3.41167*10^6, M2 -> 3.43861*10^6, M3 -> 3.43861*10^6, 
   M4 -> 3.50753*10^6, M5 -> 3.50753*10^6, M6 -> 3.50753*10^6, 
   M7 -> 6.29868*10^6, M8 -> 6.29868*10^6}}[[1, All, 2]]` returns only the numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {{2.85408*10^6, 2.86829*10^6, 2.86829*10^6, 2.90463*10^6, 
   2.90463*10^6, 2.90463*10^6, 5.64623*10^6, 5.64623*10^6}}//Flatten;

list2 = {{M1 -> 3.41167*10^6, M2 -> 3.43861*10^6, M3 -> 3.43861*10^6, 
   M4 -> 3.50753*10^6, M5 -> 3.50753*10^6, M6 -> 3.50753*10^6, 
   M7 -> 6.29868*10^6, M8 -> 6.29868*10^6}}//Flatten;

data = Thread@{list1, list2[[All, 2]]}
ListLinePlot[data, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that the lists you are using are not the same as the ones in the OP: the latter are nested one level deeper. You may want tot adjust your answer to work directly with those lists instead.

Comment: This is an interesting usage of `Thread`, achieving the intended result of transposing the lists, rather than using `Transpose`

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, I have edited the lists.